# React native push notification background color

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

How set background color in react native using react native push notification npm package?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this in the manifest file for Android

```
 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

for more details visit this [link](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android#Default-icon-and-color-(Optional))